# Slow query on a large table when using order by

Tags: sql, postgresql, indexing, postgresql-9.3, postgresql-performance

I have a table with ~30M tuples. The table looks like:

```
id | first_name | last_name | email
-----------------------------------------
1  | foo        | bar       | foo@bar.com
```

Also there are an index (btree index) for first_name and other for last_name.

The query below tooks about 200ms to return the results:

```
SELECT  
  * 
FROM my_table 
 WHERE (first_name ILIKE 'a%') 
 LIMIT 10 OFFSET 0
```

But the next one tooks about 15 seconds (adding the order by)

```
SELECT  
  * 
FROM my_table 
 WHERE (first_name ILIKE 'a%') 
 ORDER BY last_name asc, first_name asc 
 LIMIT 10 OFFSET 0
```

What can I do to improve the performance of the last query?

Comment: Index last_name, first_name.

Comment: https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Slow_Query_Questions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have two choices of indexes for this query:

```
SELECT t.* 
FROM my_table 
WHERE first_name ILIKE 'a%'
ORDER BY last_name asc, first_name asc 
LIMIT 10 OFFSET 0 ;
```

One is for the `WHERE` clause.  The best index for this is `my_table(first_name)`.  The second possibility is to use an index for the `ORDER BY`, `my_table(last_name, first_name)`.

Which is better depends on the data you have.  You might want to try both to see which works better, if overall performance is a goal.

Finally, a computed index might be the best way to go.  For your case, write the query as:

```
SELECT t.* 
FROM my_table 
WHERE lower(substr(first_name, 1, 1)) = 'a'
ORDER BY last_name asc, first_name asc 
LIMIT 10 OFFSET 0 ;
```

Then, the index you want is `mytable(lower(substr(first_name, 1, 1)), last_name, first_name)`.  This index can be used for both the `WHERE` and the `ORDER BY`, which should be optimal for this query.

Answer (score 1):

I assume the following index will speed up the `ORDER BY`:

```
create index my_table_lname_fname on my_table (last_name, first_name)
```

Answer (score 0):

`CREATE INDEX my_table_idx1 ON my_table (last_name ASC NULLS LAST, first_name ASC NULLS LAST);`

Some notes in no particular order:

- The ASC NULLS LAST is the default but I thought I would illustrate in case you want to play withe ordering.

  - This is one of those rare times where a multi-column index will help you. *Generally* you are advised to create numerous single column indexes and allow the query optimizer the luxury of selecting the indexes to use rather than forcing it into a decision.
  - I noticed an ILIKE in there which is is not performant and might be your real problem *unless* you are using the pg_trgm package along with a GIST index.